# How to retrieve only one desired image from a folder in database using its name?

Tags: php, html, mysql

We have saved lots of images in uploads folder in root folder. But we want to display only a single image for each user profile.

The name of the image is stored in database table `user` in the field `profile_image`. Now using this name I need to retrieve the same name image from uploads folder.

```
<?php
$filename=mysql_query("SELECT profile_image FROM user WHERE username='$user_check'");
?>

<div id="photo">
<?php
echo "<img src='uploads/".$filename."' class='img'/>";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to fetch the results from the query. Try [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT profile_image FROM user WHERE username='$user_check'" LIMIT 1");   
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $filename=$row['profile_image'];
        }

<div id="photo">
<?php
echo "<img src='uploads/".$filename."' class='img'/>";
?>
</div>
```

you can use mysql and not mysqli if you want

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.